# PHP Foreach: 2 columns, 1 row, repeatedly

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to **produce this** with php foreach loop:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">

     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            DATA
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            DATA
        </div>

     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Current** PHP Code:

```
$form = '';

$form .= '<form>';

$count = 0;
foreach ($fields as $f) {

   // open .form-group and .row every two loops?
   if($count % 2) $form .='<div class="form-group"><div class="row">';
   $form .= '<div class="col-sm-6">'; // always open column

   $form .= 'Whatever data';

   $form .= '</div>'; // always close column

   // close .form-group and .row every two loops?
   if($count % 2) $form .= '</div></div>';

   $count++;
}


$form .= '</form>';
```

I tried many possible ways, this is just an example of my code.

The point is to start the `.form-group` and `.row` and then loop twice the columns without the wrappers, if that makes any sense.

If I use `if ($count % 2 == 0)` instead, I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC1Rd.png

A

Comment: @Barmar That's why I'm here asking questions I suppose

Comment: where is `$fields` defined?

Comment: `0 % 2` (as `2 % 2`) is __FALSE__, see?

Comment: @Pamblam doesn't really matter. It's a stripped down code

Comment: @u_mulder as said, this is just an example. I've tried many ways. I think there is something apart from odd/even looping and foreach that has to be used here

Comment: mulder's point is that on the first iteration it's going to be false. you wan it to be true the first time. throw a `!` in front of it or start with the number one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first

```
if ($count % 2)
```

to

```
if ($count % 2 == 0)
```

Change the second one to:

```
if ($count % 2 != 0)
```

(This second change isn't strictly necessary, but I think it makes the code clearer.)

You want to start a new DIV when `$count` is even, and end it when `$count` is odd. But `$count % 2` is `0` when it's even, and that's falsey.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/DNJQvQ)

Note that if there can be an odd number of items in $fields, you'll need an extra check after the loop to close the last DIV. So at the end of the loop, do:

```
if ($count % 2 != 0) {
    // Close the last DIV if there are an odd number of fields
    $form .= '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: or `!($count % 2)` or just start `$count` off at an odd number'

Comment: @jQuerybeast The problem is that you were opening AND closing the DIV around the same row when `$count` matched the condition. The conditions for opening and closing are different. I've edited the answer.

Comment: YES! THIS! Thank you

Comment: @Barmar Can you please explain me about the items of $fields being odd?

Comment: You want to start a DIV before item 0, end it after item 1, start another DIV before item 2, end it after item 3, and so on.

Comment: @barmar I meant about the extra check after the loop to close the last div

Comment: I added to the answer

Comment: It shouldn't work as its the same with even number of fields "if ($count % 2 != 0)"

Comment: Is it possible you could update your ideone.com about it?

Comment: I've added it to the demo, and changed to 5 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Condition is incorrect, In this situation a for loop might more appropriated:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < count($fields); $count++) {
   if($count % 2 === 0){
      //even
   }else{
      //odd
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem with the logic for when to open and close the DIVs.